# create list of object with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arraylist

I have an array of strings, I use this code to add a new item

```
 $scope.list.push(name);
```

But I don't want to add only the name, I want to do something like

```
$scope.list.push(data); // data contain name and age
```

How can I create data object ?

Comment: Show `complete` code.

Comment: var data={"name":"user","age":15};$scope.list.push(data);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just write

```
var data = {name : "sampleName", age : 18};
$scope.list.push(data);
```